# What Does "Little Womp Rat" Mean?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

That comparison first appeared in the Attack of the Clones shooting script during a scene with Anakin and Watto.

Watto calls Anakin a "little womp rat" before remarking that he "sure sprouted." What did he mean?

Is Watto literally calling him a dwarf, or is it a term of endearment on Tatooine?

Edit: I'm referring to the way Watto used womp rat.

Edit 2 - exact dialogue:

WATTO
(continuing in English)
You are Annie! It is you! You
little womp rat!

WATTO gives ANAKIN a big hug.

WATTO
(continuing)
Ya sure sprouted! Weehoo! A Jedi! Waddya know? Hey, maybe you couldda help me wit some deadbeats who owe...

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Womp_rat

Comment: The term certainly did not first appear in Attack of the Clones; Luke said he used to "bullseye womp rats" (comparing them to the size of the Death Star exhaust port) in A New Hope. But it's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: I'm not referring to "womp rat" itself, but rather, "little womp rat."

Comment: I think he's suggesting that Anakin is annoying and chews through cables.

Comment: A womp rat is a large rat-like creature, roughly 2 meters in lengths from nose to tail. Watto is saying that Anakin was much smaller than this (a small, weedy boy) when he knew him as a child, but that he's sprouted (grown considerably) since then and is now about the same size as an adult womp rat.

Comment: In episode 9 of The Mandalorian Peli Motto uses "little womp rat" as a term of endearment for The Child.  So it seems like a pretty common colloquialism on Tatooine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Little" in this case, is used as a diminutive modifier which works both as an actual indication of youth, which is often correlated with a lack of strength, knowledge, or sense, and as an intensifier of an insult as in the [common English usage](https://www.englishbaby.com/vocab/word/12155/you-little) of "you little stinker". In this case, since it is an older Anakin, Watto is using it in the second form, but doing it in a more affectionate manner, much like how one of my friends will address her children as "little stinkers" much to their amusement, even though they are now much older.